# Is "gaijin" considered offensive?

Tags: word-choice, offensive-language, ethnonyms

Is *gaijin* a term that's only acceptable when it's a non-Japanese person using it self-referentially (similar to [n-word privileges](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NWordPrivileges) in TV Tropes), or is it considered ok to use in normal conversation between non-Japanese and Japanese?

For example, could one say, "Can you rewrite that address in romaji so us gaijin can understand it?", or would it be better to use a more bland term?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is about English language and usage. *Gaijin* is a Japanese word...

Comment: @Philoto: A loanword?

Comment: It's a loanword in English, as attested by its modern usage and its presence in dictionaries. As such,the question of its usage and perceived meaning is on topic.

Comment: It's actually "romaji" (long "o") to be 100% Japanesely incorrect. Romanji is a mistake of the Japanese' mistake. How sweet isn't that.

Comment: @Jonny, there is no mistake on the part of the Japanese. ローマ _Rōma_ is the Japanese form of ‘Rome’, and as Japanese has no real morphological way to form adjectives from nouns, simple compounding is often employed instead; hence ローマ字 _Rōmaji_ ‘Rome characters’. ローマン _rōman_ is an entirely different word in Japanese, quite unrelated to Rome, and ローマン字 _rōmanji_ would mean ‘romance/novel/adventure letters’.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, for my first-hand reporting of the usage (and perceived offensiveness) I observed of this word, discussing with a small Japanese community in London and Boston. *[Gaijin](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gaijin)* is fine in normal conversation, both between non-Japanese people and between Japanese and non-Japanese.

Secondly, looking up some authorities, none of the dictionaries I have at hand or checked online (*Merriam-Webster*, *Oxford*, *Cambridge*) mark it as offensive or derogatory.

Thirdly, I thought about similar words for other communities. You gave the example of *nigger*, which is extremely offensive (“black” or “African American” being respectful alternatives). Another one is *[goy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goy)*, which can be perceived as offensive depending on context and audience (and for which “Gentile” is a safer alternative).

Answer (score 6):

In my experience, the Japanese seldom use *gaijin* to your face. If they are making an effort to be polite (which they almost always are), they will call, say, an American *amerikajin* or *beikokujin* (lit. "rice-land person"). If they're really being rude (it happens) they might use *hakujin* (lit. "white person"). If you hear that and you're Caucasian you may assume that you're being talked down to, although there's still a chance the rudeness is merely condescension or ignorance.

The politer form of *gaijin* is *gaikokujin* (lit. "out-country person").

Now, in English we make no such distinction. We just tag it as their word for foreigner, which glosses over all of the nuance.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding of the word is that originally it came about just as a contraction for "gaikokujin"(foreigner) and was not meant to be offensive or anything, and in fact it still is as it was for a considerable portion of the population. Since it was translated as "foreigner" in English, visitors from English speaking countries gradually came to take it as somewhat discriminatory. More Japanese people are using the original "gaikokujin" these days after being told how "gaijin" is taken. Lots of Japanese people, especially the older generation, however, use "gaijin" without any awareness of the negative nuance. In this sense there is some essential difference from N-words in the US.

Answer (score 3):

The offensiveness inherent in the word gaijin is that it is essentially lumping together all other countries' peoples. How about a personal anecdote?

I was once in the presence of very diverse company for a work function where one Japanese person made several comments about us that were quite broad sweeping generalizations. Nothing particularly rude in and of itself, but the group she was refering to included myself (a Canadian), an American, a Spaniard, and a Khazakh.

Although you might argue that Canadians and Americans are somewhat similar, it felt pretty weird to be put in the same box as people from Spain and Kazakhstan.

In this way, the word gaikokujin is no less offensive really, it just signifies that they are attempting to be polite. However, courtesy and ignorance are not mutually exclusive. The fact that this word is frequently used points to elements of Japanese culture that are uncomfortably nationalistic. It often makes one feel that Japanese believe that are uniquely special, that the world outside of Japan is totally different or incompatible with Japanese values, that Japanese people are biologically very unique even, and ultimately it's that although Japanese people don't necessarily think they are better than everyone else, they do think that everyone else is worse than they are.

Getting back to the word gaijin, I think it's as simple as translating the word. I think the word foreigner is just as problematic, for the same reasons I mentioned above. That's why you rarely hear English speakers refer to someone as a foreigner. We at the very least take the time to categorize people roughly into european, asian, latino, and black. Of course, these are obviously problematic labels as well.

Comment: This distinction of native/foreign is common worldwide. It's just a form of ingroup/outgroup. Think of the use of "alien" at the US border, or the way people in many countries see pale skin and speak English, among many examples